# How much to store a suitcase for a month in Wellington, NZ

Tags: rental, luggage-storage, wellington

There are many self-storage type places advertising online, but nowhere has any costs listed.

Approximately how much should I expect to pay for storage space for a suitcase with self-access? Ballpark would be great, no idea if it will be $50 or $500 a month.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a ballpark only (as it's not in Wellington), [All Secure](http://allsecure.co.nz/storage-units/self-storage/) has a 'travellers' deal on their website which is $40/month for a 1 metre cubic Self Storage locker.

So given your "$50 or $500", the answer is $50 - although I suspect you may find that most places will potentially charge a little more if you're only looking for a single month.  I have a storage locker in Sydney, and it had a minimum 6 month term on it in order to get their standard prices.

Depending on how you're planning to use it, keep in mind that most self-storage places will be outside of the downtown metro area, and may not be that easy/cheap to get to if you don't have suitable transport.  You may be better talking to a hotel or (more likely) a hostel/backpackers and see if they will store it for you.

Alternatively Wellington Airport has luggage storage, but it costs ~$10/day.